# How to use orWhere in whereHas in Laravel

Tags: laravel-4

I have three tables `user`, `role`, `permission`, `user` hasMany `role`, `role` hasMany `permission`, I want to find out user who has permission I gave, therefore I use `whereHas`

```
$user = User::whereHas('roles', function($q) {
    $q->whereHas('permissions', $function($q) {
        $q->where('name', $value);
    });
});
```

The result is correct, but if I want to search user by more conditions, I give the other permission value and use `orWhere`, it response all user who have any permissions, how to fix it?

```
$user = User::whereHas('roles', function($q) {
    $q->whereHas('permissions', $function($q) {
        $q->where('name', $value)->orWhere('name', $value2);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 14):

I ran into the same problem: I wanted to implement a table search for companies. The search string shall be searched within the companies name and also in the associated contacts forename and lastname. My try was like this:

```
Company::where('name', 'like', '%'.$searchstring.'%')
         ->orWhereHas('contacts', function($q) use ($searchstring) { 
                                    $q->where('forename', 'like', '%'.$searchstring.'%')
                                    ->orWhere('lastname', 'like', '%'.$searchstring.'%');
                                   });
```

The result was similar to the one described by you: for certain searchstrings ALL companies were returned.

Only workaround I was able to figure out was separating where and orWhere of the orWhereHas-closure into TWO orWhereHas-closures. Like this:

```
Company::with('mainContact', 'contacts')
         ->where('name', 'like', '%'.$searchstring.'%')
         ->orWhereHas('contacts', function($q) use ($searchstring) { 
                                    $q->where('forename', 'like', '%'.$searchstring.'%');
                                  })
         ->orWhereHas('contacts', function($q) use ($searchstring) { 
                                    $q->where('lastname', 'like', '%'.$searchstring.'%');
                                  });
```

I am not sure if this generates a very expensive SQL-query, but it works. Any improvements of my snippet are very welcome.

Comment: This works well. However, I think we can make it more cleaner or make it more mature. Any ideas about this?

Comment: I think i have a solution for you. You have to wrap the orWhereHas inside a where. 
Example: 
`->where(function ($query) {
              $query->orWhereHas('athlete', function ($q) {
                  $q->where('first_name', 'like', '%' . \Request::get('filter') . '%');
                  $q->orWhere('last_name', 'like', '%' . \Request::get('filter') . '%');
              });
    })`

Answer (score 0):

Avoiding using *$q* variable in the first *where* should work

```
User::has('roles')->whereHas('permissions', $function($q) {
        $q->where('name', $value)->orWhere('name', $value2);
    });
```

Comment: User does not have relationship with permission, it's not work.

Comment: I meant to say "roles" instead of "permissions" in the first "where" clause. I've updated the answer, This should work.

Comment: I know, I tried, it shows Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::permissions()